# Can I download the Stack Overflow editor?

Tags: support, feature-request, markdown

Whenever I have to write a (very) long answer or even a complete Q/A, I work on my text when I am off-line. Meaning I'm not using the Stack Overflow editor and thus can not benefit from the invaluable preview window. Once my text is ready for publication I paste it on the answer page, and then I'm faced with the daunting task of getting everything in place. Often at this point things look messy!

Is it possible to **download** Stack Overflow's excellent editor as **a stand-alone desktop application** so that in future once I've pasted my text on the answer page, I can straight away click the PostYourAnswer button?

Comment: I think that the editor is very close to a markdown editor, which you could get as a standalone application or even a offline browser extension.

Comment: If you are using VS on a regular basis, this may be of interest: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor

Comment: https://stackedit.io claims to use Stack Overflow syntax. Never used it, may be amazing, may be terrible - use at your own risk!

Comment: A markdown editor is all you need - except SO doesn't use ` ``` ` for codes, but 4-space indentation instead. Note the difference and it'll be all clear.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow uses a flavor of Markdown, which while largely compatible with mainstream Markdown, can be a *little* bit different.

However, if you want to get the basic text in, you are somewhat spoiled for choice when it comes to Markdown editors.  I would toss a recommendation for [Simplenote](https://simplenote.com/) because it allows you to do this on any device you wish to.

I could appreciate wanting a way to post directly from desktop, but that would beget some kind of destkop app for Stack Overflow, which currently doesn't exist - it's all in-browser.